# Verification of this integration on forms by two different methods

Tags: integration, solution-verification, differential-forms

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the upper half ball with radius $a$, i.e. the region bounded below by $z=0$ and above by $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$. Compute
$$ \int_{\partial\Omega} xz\,dy\wedge dz + yz\,dz\wedge dx + (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\wedge dy. $$

I have computed this integral directly and by Stokes' theorem, but I got different results.

Let $V=\{(r,\theta):0<r<a, 0<\theta<2\pi\}$ and $U=\{(\phi, \theta):0<\phi<\pi/2,0<\theta<2\pi\}$.

$$\begin{align*}
    &\int_{\partial\Omega} xz\,dy\wedge dz + yz\,dz\wedge dx + (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\wedge dy \\
    =& \int_{V} r^2\,d(r\cos\theta)\wedge d(r\sin\theta) \\
&+ \int_{U} (a\sin\phi\cos\theta)(a\cos\phi)\, d(a\sin\phi\sin\theta)\wedge d(a\cos\phi) \\
    &+ \int_{U} (a\sin\phi\sin\theta)(a\cos\phi)\, d(a\cos\phi)\wedge d(a\sin\phi\cos\theta) \\
     &+\int_{U} a^2\, d(a\sin\phi\cos\theta)\wedge d(a\sin\phi\sin\theta) \\
    =& \int_{V} r^3\,dr\wedge d\theta \\
&+ \int_{U} (a\sin\phi\cos\theta)(a\cos\phi)(a^2\sin^2\phi\cos\theta)\, d\phi\wedge d\theta \\
    &+ \int_{U} (a\sin\phi\sin\theta)(a\cos\phi)(a^2\sin^2\phi\sin\theta)\, d\phi\wedge d\theta \\
     &+\int_{U} a^2(a^2\cos\phi\sin\phi)\, d\phi\wedge d\theta \\
    =& \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a r^3\,dr\,d\theta \\
&+ a^4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\pi} (\sin^3\phi\cos\phi\cos^2\theta+\sin^3\phi\cos\phi\sin^2\theta+\cos\phi\sin\phi)\,d\theta\,d\phi \\
    =&\  2\pi a^4.
\end{align*}$$

By Stokes' theorem,
$$
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\partial\Omega} xz\,dy\wedge dz + yz\,dz\wedge dx + (x^2+y^2+z^2)\,dx\wedge dy \\
    =& \int_{\Omega} (z+z+2z)\,dx\wedge dy\wedge dz \\
    =& \int_0^a\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\pi} (4\rho\cos\phi) (\rho^2\sin\phi)\, d\theta\,d\phi\,d\rho \\
    =&\ \pi a^4.
\end{align*}
$$

I have been debugging for hours, but I'm still struggling to find a mistake.

Comment: You did not integrate over the whole boundary, it is piecewise. Where is your integral on the plane $z=0$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi The first term is the integration on $z=0$, i.e. the term $\int_V r^2\,d(r\cos\theta)\wedge d(r\sin\theta)$.

Comment: It is done incorrectly, the correct outward facing normal would be $dy\wedge dx$, not $dx\wedge dy$

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your work but over the disk at $z = 0$, it should be  $ ~ \displaystyle - \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a r^3 dr ~ d\theta ~ $. Note the minus sign as the outward normal vector is pointing downward.